# Regular Expression to Match " | "

Tags: java, regex, parsing, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to use Java's [`useDelimiter`](http://www.ensta.fr/%7Ediam/java/online/jdk/150/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) method on it's `Scanner` class to do some simple parsing. Basically each line is a record delimited by " | ", so for example:

```
2 | John Doe
3 | Jane Doe
4 | Jackie Chan
```

The method takes as a parameter a regular expression for which to match for. Can someone please provide me with the regular expression that would match `|` (A vertical bar separated by one space on both sides).

Thanks, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: java must have some kind of string split function. you can use that.

Comment: yeah that's actually what I ended up doing, but I'm still using the regex to split the line string :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I came up with `\s\|\s` which in Java would be expressed as `"\\s\\|\\s"`. I don't know if this is the best one though. I don't need anything hardcore, just something that works, and this seems to :)

Sorry for answering my own question, I guess after typing it out it helped me think.

Comment: Just be careful, `\s` would be any white-space character, including `\t`!  So you may want to be more specific, depending on your input set.

Comment: I agree--I would go with `" \\| "` as my argument to useDelimiter

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code snippet that parses a string (or a whole File, Scanner accepts both), and extracts the number and name from each line :

```
String s = 
    "1 | Mr John Doe\n" + 
    "2 | Ms Jane Doe\n" + 
    "3 | Jackie Chan\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) \\| ((\\w|\\s)+)");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(s);
while (scan.findInLine(pattern) != null) {
    MatchResult match = scan.match();

    // Do whatever appropriate with the results
    System.out.printf("N° %d is %s %n", Integer.valueOf(match.group(1)), match.group(2));

    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        scan.nextLine();
    }
}
```

This code snippet produces the following result :

```
N° 1 is Mr John Doe
N° 2 is Ms Jane Doe
N° 3 is Jackie Chan
```

Comment: cool! split() has an argument of regular expression so you need to use \| to represent a bar, in a string it is "\\|".

Answer (score 2):

```
" \| "
```

would work, you need to escape quotes and the |

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to include the * to match repeating character

```
\S*\s*\|\s*[\S\t ]*
```

Edited --
You can use simply this too `.*\|.*`

Answer (score 0):

......

```
^[ \| ]?$
```